# Trying to buy a replacement battery but I worry about whether it will be compatible due to the differnce in voltage and capacity

Tags: laptop, battery, replacement

I'm going to replace my HP 740004-121 OA04 battery,the originally is 14.8v but the one I'm looking to buy is only 14.4v. Would this not power my computer fully or not fit or be dangerous in any way?It also has less capacity will it totally not work in my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain the battery will fit?  Lower voltage (in this case not much) means lower capacity when only on battery.

It is unusual in my experience that a properly fitting battery would have a different voltage, unless somehow a cheap knock-off battery.

So consider the voltage (warning sign) and the quality (may not perform well or last long).